# Dispatching grpc requests to multiple servers via Nginx

Tags: nginx, grpc, nginx-config

Having a grpc `client` and `server` and they are exchanging messages in **grpc** unary mode. I want to log all the messages the `client` sends to the `server` without changing a single line of  code in both `client` or `server`. I came across to ***Nginx*** with its new graceful **grpc** support. Is it possible to route **grpc** messages from `client` to `server` via ***Nginx*** while sending a copy of them to a remote logging service? If No, please let me know if there are any other tools out there that do the same stuff.

Comment: Hi, perhaps have nginx [log the request](https://serverfault.com/questions/636790/nginx-log-complete-request-response-with-all-headers) or use the [mirror module](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mirror_module.html) to replay the request to a second server.

Comment: I don't want to use nginx logs and I prefer mirroring. I wonder if mirror_module supports grpc requests. Similar question on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/nginx/comments/fzyx4z/can_we_mirror_grpc_traffic_using_nginx_and/